# Finder window reappears if still open

Tags: finder

I am sure this question was asked somewhere but just could not figure out precisely how to describe the behaviour so as to find the answer. I have multiple windows open on the screen. The one in the foreground is a Finder window, then some other stuff and then another Finder window in the background. If I close the Finder window in the foreground then the one in the background appears. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Are you just trying to close the foreground Finder window or all open Finder windows at one time?

Comment: No only the one in the foreground. I would cmd+q to close all windows

Comment: You cannot ordinarily Quit the Finder [without some tweaking behind the scenes]. It stays active always.

Answer (score 2):

I know of no way to do this if the Finder is the frontmost app at the start of your sequence. It's fairly standard practice that if you close the frontmost window in any app, the next behind it will come to focus.

However, if Finder is **not** the frontmost app, then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> -clicking the red dot will close the window without bringing the Finder to the front.

There are a few  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  + action functions that will operate on a window without bringing it to the front - you can drag window edges to resize, minimise, close, etc.

You can kind of 'fake' what you want if you click on the Desktop first, then when you close your first window, the Desktop itself will be 'frontmost'... yet of course will not actually move.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple windows open temporarily click one of the non-finder windows to bring it to the front. Move it left or right so you can the the red and green buttons of the finder window you want to close. Click on the red button of the finder window.